# 'adb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to learn react-native and now I'm trying to run my react-native app on my android device (not emulator) from the react-native document I can see my connected device by typing the "adb devices" on the terminal. But I can't do it in my case and it shows some error like this

```
adb : The term 'adb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,   
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ adb devices
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (adb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I believe the issue is that you have not added the necessary variables to your path. To confirm this run `react-native doctor`. If you dont have react-native installed globally try `npx react-native doctor`.  If you add the results to the answer I can try to help